# Expo React Native - Fetch all data before rendering app

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want my app to fetch all data from firebase database before rendering the actual app by using AppLoading component of expo. I wrap my app inside a provider and call fetchCoreData(), however, the app is still loaded even the state of the context hasn't been finished.

I am wondering if there is a way to force it to be fully loaded before rendering the app.

Thank you.

```
 const App = () => {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = React.useState(false);
  const { fetchCoreData } = React.useContext(CoreDataContext);

  const _cacheResourceAsync = async () => {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
      ...Ionicons.font,
    });
    fetchCoreData();
  };

  if (!isReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={_cacheResourceAsync}
        onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)}
        onError={console.warn}
      />
    );
  }

  return <Index />;
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <CoreDataProvider>
      <App />
    </CoreDataProvider>
  );
};
```